# Find the record duplicate and say the duplicate count for every record

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table having repeated value  family name. I want a column showing number that how many times the family name repeated for each record.

Input:

| First Name | Family Name |
| --- | --- |
| George | bush |
| Donald | trump |
| Ilana | trump |
| David | trump |
| Robert | bush |
| Amber | Monk |

Expected out put

| First Name | Family Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| George | bush | 2 |
| Donald | trump | 3 |
| Ilana | trump | 3 |
| David | trump | 3 |
| Robert | bush | 2 |
| Amber | Monk | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using window function as well.

```
select
    [First Name],
    [Family Name],
    count ([Family Name]) over (partition by [Family Name])
from
    Table1
```

Comment: Not "as well".  This is the preferred method.  There is no need to repeat the column name for `count()`, so `count(*)` would work as well -- and is much easier to type.

Answer (score 0):

Model should add new property count.
So model has 3 property,Firstname,FamilyNameand count.
Then after fetching the data from db into a list you have to run a nested loop to count all repeated family name.
Example : say list name is namelist,

```
foreach(var item in namelist) {

 string name = item.FamilyName;

foreach(var item2 in namelist){

if(name== item2.FamilyName){

count++;

}
}

item.Count = count;

}
```